How to embed Google Tasks in Google Chrome Sidepanel
Goal: I'm trying to create a Google Chrome Extension with the sole purpose of interacting with Google Tasks in the Google Chrome sidebar. Similar to the sidebar available within Gmail (https://mail.google.com/), but for any site.
My setup:
sidebar.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Tasks</title>
        <style>
        html, body, iframe {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: none;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://tasks.google.com/"></iframe> 
    </body>
</html>

manifest.json:
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Google Tasks Sidebar",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Quick access to Google Tasks in the sidebar.",
    "permissions": [ "sidePanel" ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://tasks.google.com/*",
        "*://*/*"
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Toggle Google Tasks Sidebar"
    },
    "commands": {
        "toggle_sidebar": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Alt+V"
            },
            "description": "Toggle Google Tasks sidebar"
        }
    },
    "side_panel": {
        "default_path": "sidebar.html",
        "default_title": "Google Tasks"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
}

background.js:
let sidebarOpen = false;

chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
    if (command === "toggle_sidebar") {
        toggleSidebar();
    }
});

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => {
    toggleSidebar();
});

function toggleSidebar() {
    if (sidebarOpen) {
        // Close the sidebar if it's already open
        chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({ enabled: false });
        sidebarOpen = false;
    } else {
        // Open the sidebar
        chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({
            path: "sidebar.html",
            enabled: true
        });
        sidebarOpen = true;
    }
}

(NOTE: the javascript is only used to toggle the sidebar. Have mainly tested by clicking the extension icon).
When opening the extensions sidebar, I receive:
Google
403. That’s an error.
We're sorry, but you do not have access to this document. That’s all we know.

Using this URL instead https://tasks.google.com/embed/ origin=https://mail.google.com&fullWidth=1 I instead receive:
tasks.google.com refused to connect.

I'm not really sure if my errors are related to CORS policies(?) or the logged in user not being passed on to the iframe.
Have I set something up incorrectly int terms of getting the Google Tasks UI to load insinde the side panel?
Is the any way for the extension to ask permission to Google Tasks or similar to be able to load the UI inside the sidebar?
